# Java EE - Testing in Glassfish with EclipseLink (Derby or Enbedded Derby) and deploying in Openshift jBoss with Hibernate (MySQL). Is this possible?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish, eclipselink

I believe this is a reasonable scenario.

I started developing an application with EclipseLink Glassfish and both Derby and Embedded Derby (the latter for integration tests).

Now I want to move it to Openshift which provides a JBoss Application Server (so I would prefer Hibernate) and MySQL database.

Is there any clever way to achieve this kind of flexibility? Using maven perhaps?

Comment: If you plan to deploy on JBoss, Hibernate and MySQL, then by all means use them for your tests. Testing on a different app server, different ORM and different database won't tell you if the code works fine on the target platform.

Comment: i don't know about the app servers but isn't that (one of) the purpose of ORMs? to abstract the data access layer so it can be interchangeable? If I don't get into very specific vendor operations why should that be a problem? Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: You will probably hit small differences in behavior, even if that's not supposed to happen. And the complexity of targetting 2 different platforms when you just target one is not free. The SQL syntax and types of both databases will differ, etc. Why make your life complex?

Comment: You have a point obviously. The thing is, I have a pretty good setup right now. I run integration tests through arquillian with embedded glassfish and embedded derby and they run really fast. So to change this would make my life complex!